# Issue when doing web scraper

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I am scraping the webpage `https://www.g2a.com/rising-storm-2-vietnam-steam-cd-key-global.html`

I need to get the title from the table data.

```
    var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var app = express();

app.get('/scrape', function(req, res) {

    url = 'https://www.g2a.com/rising-storm-2-vietnam-steam-cd-key-global.html';

    request(url, function(error, response, body) {
        if (!error) {
            var $ = cheerio.load(body);


            var arr = [];

            var title = $('.mp-user-rating tr').each(function() {
                var tableData = $('.marketplace-name > .mp-rating-popup');
                arr.push({ 'title': tableData.text() });
            });
        }
        res.send('Check your console!')

    });
})
app.listen('8081');

console.log('Magic happens on port 8081');

exports = module.exports = app;
```

Here the data is in third column and cannot able to get `.mp-user-rating tr` data what is expected.

[image]

The image shows the structure of the table

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: @mplungjan No error

Comment: You will likely get more answers here: https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/issues

Comment: `arr.push({ 'title': tableData.text() });` … and then what? You never touch the `arr` variable again. Why do you expect to get anything?

Comment: My answer seems to be what you want. But like others have said, you aren't doing anything with the arr variable.

Comment: Quentin matt ; I am trying to achieve till that array then I'll send that as response to the client side.

Answer (score -1):

So, I went to the page and ran this in the console.

```
var arr = [];
var title = jQuery('.mp-user-rating tr').each(function(i, element) {
   var tableData = jQuery(element).find('.mp-rating-popup');
   arr.push({ 'title': tableData.text() });
});
console.log(arr);
```

The array consists of 8 objects that each have the titles within them.

UPDATE:

I pulled in the html information using your code. I think the issue is, the html is loaded asynchronously by the website, as a result, pulling the html will only retrieve the static markup. You will need to use PhantomJS or chrome's headless browser in order to load the website and allow the asyncronous information to load, then you can grab the html.

See here for some good docs on PhantomJS: https://github.com/Medium/phantomjs

Comment: Thank you for the answer ;but Its not working when I am doing through node js

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: HTML page content retrieved via a url request will be static only. You need to be able to 'wait' for all asyncronous data calls to be completed so that you can get the dynamically generated html content. This is where phantomjs comes in. It'll allow you to wait for the content to load before retrieving the html content.